# Working Powershell script doesn't run properly in C#

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

This powershell script runs fine in the powershell ISE when testing it, but it encounters errors when I use system.management.automation to run it in a C# application.

```
get-adgroupmember -identity office_365 -recursive |
    get-aduser -properties mail |
        select mail -First 10
```

The error is this:

"The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input."

Here is the C# code that uses the script

```
var iss = InitialSessionState.CreateDefault2();
iss.ExecutionPolicy = Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy.Bypass;

PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(iss);
ps.AddCommand(@"C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\testScript.ps1");

var results = ps.Invoke();
```

Comment: Yeah, it returns thousands of the same error in the results array. I'm not great with powershell, but it seems like it's returning that error for each user that should be showing up in the query

Comment: Taking a closer look at your PowerShell command: `Get-ADGroupMember` doesn't just list members that are _users_, but also computers and (nested) groups - members of the latter two types cannot be piped to `Get-ADUser`, and would result in the error shown in your question.

Comment: but wouldn't that error come up if I was running the script manually? It only happens in c#

Comment: yes - unless you're somehow silencing errors when you're running locally. What types does `get-adgroupmember -identity office_365 -recursive | % GetType | Select-Object -Unique` report?

Comment: ADPrincipal                             
Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADObject

Comment: Jake, according to the [`Get-ADUser` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/get-aduser?view=windowsserver2022-ps#inputs), it (predictably) only accepts pipeline input objects of type `ADUser`.

Comment: That makes sense, I wonder why it works at all

Comment: Assuming there is at least one user among the output objects, use `get-adgroupmember -identity office_365 -recursive | Where-Object ObjectClass -eq user` to retrieve only users.

Comment: I ran this:
 `get-adgroupmember -identity office_365 -recursive | Where-object objectClass -eq "user" | % GetType | Select-Object -Unique`
and it still returned `ADPrincipal` as the type

Comment: If you actually get the _expected results_ (not just _no error_) when you run locally, I may have led you down the wrong path - sorry (I don't have access to AD). `ADPrincipal` is a base class of `ADUser`, among others. So it is conceivable that `ADPrincipal` instances whose `.ObjectClass` is `"user"` _do_ work as `Get-ADUser` input, but I don't know - however, _group_ or _computer_ principals I definitely wouldn't expect to work.

Comment: oh that makes sense. I switched it to only grab objects that aren't type `user` and it returned zero results, so i think it was a misleading non-issue. I appreciate the help though

Comment: . Now that you know that it works as expected locally, you could investigate what type is being output by `get-adgroupmember -identity office_365 -recursive` in your C# application - the error message suggests that it is different, but this should only happen if _remoting_ is involved.